# TypeError: $(...) is null - how to use noconflict()

Tags: javascript

i get error TypeError: $(...) is null.

```
<script>
$('w_pages').observe('change', function(){
    parent.preview.location = 'W/preview/<?=$page['parent_id'] ?>/?p='+$('w_pages').value;
});
$('w_layout').observe('click', function(){
    parent.preview.Tiny.showURL('S/layout/'+$('w_pages').value+'?ajax=true',true)
});
</script>
```

i read that it is because of a conflict. how do i wrap this in noConflict()

Comment: have you lookend in the documentation? http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Comment: You do realize that this is not jQuery but [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org/doc/latest/dom/dollar/index.html) right?

Comment: @Jon well... the library tag is missing. You can only guess. But yeah, jQuery doesn't fit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i fixed it. i was indeed missing the element. thanx for putting me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

There is no conflict here.

You are using the [dollar function](http://prototypejs.org/doc/latest/dom/dollar/index.html) of Prototype, which returns a reference to the element with id equal to its argument. If no such element exists in the page it returns `null`, which in turn causes the TypeError.

I don't know *why* no such element exists in your page or how to make the JS work like it should, but you can avoid the immediate error by checking the return value before calling methods on it:

```
var wPages = $('w_pages');
if (wPages) {
    wPages.observe('change', function(){
        parent.preview.location = 
            'W/preview/<?=$page['parent_id'] ?>/?p='+wPages.value;
    });
}

// The same for w_layout
```

Comment: Are you sure the OP is using Prototype, not another framework with an `observe` method?

Comment: @JanDvorak: The combination of dollar function used with an id, `null` result and `observe` looks damningly like Prototype to me. I cannot rule out the possibility of a framework I don't know about, but what do you do in this situation?

Comment: ask for clarification or (if I'm reasonably sure) state my assumptions ("assuming you're using Prototype,\n\n") :-) +1 anyways

Comment: @JanDvorak: You are right of course, and if the question was a little bit more informed I would have done exactly that. But in cases like this asking for clarification might not produce the expected results.

Comment: thanx for the assistance, this is protoype. i will check to see what element is missing.